# How can I decode an `NSCoder` with a terminal command

Tags: javascript, macos, terminal, nscoder

This is a continuation of this question I asked on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464860/where-does-pages-store-its-list-of-recently-opened-documents/464864#464864).

I am trying get the list of recently opened documents in Pages. I found the file at `~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.apple.iwork.pages.sfl2` and successfully used `plutil -convert xml1` to convert it to an xml plist file. Thanks to [@Graham Miln](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1860/graham-miln) I know that the file is encoded with an `NSCoder`.

I know absolutely nothing about Objective-C and am looking for a way to decode the file within terminal. I am decoding this file for a [raycast](https://raycast.com) extension which will be written in JavaScript. Therefore, I am either looking for a JavaScript solution or a terminal command that I can run(because it is really easy to run terminal commands in the js code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a Swift script that decodes any `sfl12` file, and prints each recent file, one file per line.

Save it and either execute with with the `swift /path/to/saved/file </path/to/sfl12/file>`, or make the file executable and directly execute it.

The script expects the path to the `sfl12` file as first argument.

Note that you need to install the Xcode Command Line Tools in order to be able to execute swift scripts.

```swift
#!/usr/bin/swift
import Foundation

do {
    guard CommandLine.arguments.count > 1 else {
        throw "Please provide the path to the file"
    }

    let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(filePath: CommandLine.arguments[1]))
    guard let root = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSDictionary.self, NSArray.self], 
                                                            from: data) as? [String: Any] else {
        throw "Invalid top level object, expected a dictionary"
    }

    guard let items = root["items"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
        throw "Invalid items property, expected an array of dictionaries"
    }

    for item in items {
        var stale = false
        if let bookmarkData = item["Bookmark"] as? Data,
           let url = try? URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, bookmarkDataIsStale: &stale) {
                print(url.path)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    exit(-1)
}

extension String: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? { self }
}
```

Sample output:

```
> swift ~/Downloads/recent-files.swift "/Users/<myusername>/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.apple.iwork.pages.sfl2"

/Users/<myusername>/Documents/test2.pages
/Users/<myusername>/Desktop/test.pages
```

Comment: It told me that I did not have permission to open the file, even when running with `sudo`. I temporarily got around this by duplicating the file in finder and moving it to a different directory, but is there a way I can give it the permissions to decode it from its default directory?

Comment: This is related to how macOS handles accesses to the file system. You should've been asked at some point if you want to give Terminal (or whatever tool you use to execute the script) access to that location.